# How to get woocommerce product attribute description?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get value from woocommerce product attribute description input.

[image]

[image]

I tried `$discription = $attributes->description;` and also `$product_attribute['description']`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the product object, you can get the description like so

```
$productObject->get_short_description();
```

Otherwise initialize the product with the ID first and then get the description

```
$productObject = wc_get_product( $productId );
$productObject->get_short_description();
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you, but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: I still can't figure it out. Can you please tell me to do it?
Thank you.